# Django: weird behavior of foreign key lookup and annotate F expression

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

```
class Sentence(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Tokens(Model):
   token = CharField()
   sentence = ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='tokens')

Sentence.objects.annotate(n=Count('tokens', distinct=True)).filter(n=5).filter(tokens__name__in=['se']).annotate(n0=F('tokens')).filter(tokens__name__in=['faire']).annotate(n1=F('tokens')).filter(tokens__name__in=['faire']).annotate(n2=F('tokens')).filter(tokens__name__in=['un']).annotate(n3=F('tokens')).filter(tokens__name__in=['avoir']).annotate(n4=F('tokens'))
```

Above code generates the following query:

```
SELECT "sentence"."id", "sentence"."name", COUNT(DISTINCT "token"."id") AS "n", T3."id" AS "n0", T4."id" AS "n1", T4."id" AS "n2", T6."id" AS "n3", T6."id" AS "n4" FROM "sentence" LEFT OUTER JOIN "token" ON ("sentence"."id" = "token"."sentence_id") INNER JOIN "token" T3 ON ("sentence"."id" = T3."sentence_id") INNER JOIN "token" T4 ON ("sentence"."id" = T4."sentence_id") INNER JOIN "token" T5 ON ("sentence"."id" = T5."sentence_id") INNER JOIN "token" T6 ON ("sentence"."id" = T6."sentence_id") INNER JOIN "token" T7 ON ("sentence"."id" = T7."sentence_id") WHERE (T3."name" IN (se) AND T4."name" IN (faire) AND T5."name" IN (un) AND T6."name" IN (avoir) AND T7."name" IN (faire)) GROUP BY "word_frword"."id", T3."id", T4."id", T6."id" HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "token"."id") = 5
```

Why is numbering so strange (starts with `T3`)? But moreover why `n2` is assigned to `T4`, not `T5`? Same for `n4` and `T6`. Looks like numbers go by 2.

What I want to accomplish is capture token id on each step of inner join. It works when there are one join, but then it breaks.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that the exact SQL generated?  It looks like it's missing a comma (,) between `"sentence.name"` and `COUNT(DISTINCT "token"."id") AS "n"`.  What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I just removed some fields for brevity, missed comma. There is no error. I think query is incorrect.